# ValueMember from ComboBox to int

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

i have valueMember in combobox and i need to save this value to integer...
This is my code:

```
public class Benzinky
{
   public int B_cislo { get; set; }
   public string Benzinka { get; set; }
}

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:...\pokus.txt");
var data = lines.Select(l => l.Split());
List<Benzinky> allB = data.Where(arr => arr.Length >= 2
                               && arr[1].Trim().All(Char.IsDigit))
                           .Select(arr =>
                              new Benzinky
                              {
                                 Benzinka = arr[0].Trim(),
                                 B_cislo = int.Parse(arr[1].Trim())
                              })
                           .ToList();
var bindingSourceB = new BindingSource();
bindingSourceB.DataSource = allB;
comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSourceB;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "B_cislo";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Benzinka";
```

my txt:

```
Prague 3106
Berlin 3107
........
```

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should convert the *valueMember* of *comboBox1* to an integer and put the result in `Number`. This can be done in multiple ways, you can use `Convert.ToInt32();`
But I would take a look at `Int32.Parse()` and `Int32.TryParse()`

**Int32.Parse**

```
Number = Int32.Parse(comboBox1.ValueMember);
```

Above code should do the trick, but you will run in to troubles when the *string* doesn't contain a value that can be parsed to an integer, an exception will be thrown.

You could use `Int32.TryParse` if you would like to get a bool value in return instead of an exception.

**Int32.TryParse**

```
int Number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.ValueMember, out Number);
if (result)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", comboBox1.ValueMember, Number);         
}
else
{
  //conversion failed
  //Int32.Parse, would throw a formatexception here.
}
```

Could you try following code:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSourceB;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "B_cislo";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Benzinka";
int Number;
if(Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.ValueMember, out Number))
{
  //Conversion succeeded
}
else
{
  //Conversion failed, you should send a message to the user
  //Or fill Number with a default value, your choice.
}
```

Sources:

[MSDN Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[MSDN Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I have this numbers, for example: 3106, or 3101....When i use Parse i have error: Input string was not in correct format......When i use Tryparse, i Have number 00, not my 3106..:/

Comment: I can see that you are filling comboBox1.ValueMember with "B_cislo", so it will always fail converting, since it isn't a parsable int value

Answer (score 3):

`ValueMember` is just used to **determine** the value of your combobox **SelectedValue**. To get the `valueMember` part of your `ComboBox item`, you have to cast the underlying item (which is of type `Benzinky` in your example) to the correct type and get the desired value from some property, here is how it should be done if you know the underlying data type and `valueMember` beforehand:

```
int x = ((Benzinky) comboBox1.Items[index]).B_cislo;
//or using dynamic
dynamic item = comboBox1.Items[index];
int x = item.B_cislo;
```

However if you want something dynamic (that happen when the `valueMember` may change prorammatically at some time), you have to use `Reflection` like this:

```
object item = comboBox1.Items[index];
var x = (int) item.GetType().GetProperty(comboBox1.ValueMember)
                            .GetValue(item, null);
```

**NOTE**: However the `Reflection` approach is applicable only when the `DataSource` of your comboBox is not some class like `DataTable`, because a `DataTable` exposes its `Column name` as `ValueMember` not any properties of it, the underlying item will be a `DataRowView` and so in that case the reflection code will fail.